# Trying create a procedure that takes user input in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a procedure to take user input for username and password, but I keep getting an error because of the `'&'`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Approval (Input_S_ID Sales.Sales_ID%Type, discount_amount NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER 
IS    

   UN Employee.E_un%Type := &UN; 
   PS Employee.E_pass%Type := &PS;
```

Comment: Why don't you simply pass those values as function parameters?

Comment: `&` is not a special character in PL/SQL, and PL/SQL does not prompt interactively. You would need some other framework or tool to manage the interaction (Shellscript, PowerShell, Perl etc).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `directly` receive messages from the `client` in a `PL/SQL` procedure

The best way to this is to interface with table data, and have users insert data into the table and react to that, or use `Advanced Queueing` (which amounts to pretty much the same thing).

Alternatively, accept the user input as parameters when the procedure is called.

> Further more elaboration please find link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551087/pl-sql-how-do-i-prompt-user-input-in-a-procedure).